# Login verification fails while checking for userid, password from text file

Tags: python

I am currently making a python GUI with a login verification. I am using a text file to verify the login details. When I try to compare the userid and password against data from the file, it goes into the else condition and prints `"Fail"`.

I am using tkinter for the GUI, but the login details do not work.

```
from tkinter import *

def verify_login():
    file = open("login.txt","r")
    for row in file:
        field = row.split(",")
        if username.get() == field[0] and password.get() == field[1]:
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Fail")

### LOGIN SCREEN ###
def LoginPage():
    global username
    global password
    login_screen=Tk()
    login_screen.title("Login")
    login_screen.geometry("300x250")
    Label(login_screen, text="Please enter login details").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="Username").pack()
    username=StringVar()
    password=StringVar()
    username_login = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username)
    username_login.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="Password").pack()
    password_login= Entry(login_screen, textvariable=password, show= '*')
    password_login.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(login_screen, text="Login", width=10, height=1,command=verify_login).pack()
    login_screen.mainloop(

      

### MAIN SCREEN ###
def Startpage():
    global gui
    gui=Tk(className="Login Form")
    gui.geometry("500x200")
    button = Button(gui, text='Login', width=20, height=3, bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff', activebackground='#0052cc', activeforeground='#aaffaa', command=LoginPage).pack()
    gui.mainloop()
Startpage()
```

my text file has logins and passwords in this format:
`login,a,yex,joe,morgan,1,sanjay,2`

Comment: Please add an actual example of the text file

Comment: what does the debugger tell you what the `row` variable contains and the variables `username` and `password`

Comment: The debugger does not tell me anything about these, but just says that the username and password is incorrect in the console by printing "Fail"

Comment: The problem is at least partly related to creating more than one instance of `Tk`.

Answer (score 2):

maybe username and password have tailing whitespaces, like `sanjay`  and `sanjay` are not same.

to clean it up you can do this before comparing:

`username.get().rstrip()`

`password.get().rstrip()`

this rstrip() function will remove the tailing whitespaces.

also, make sure, your file has every username password pair in a new line.

then you can do this:

`for row in file.readlines():`

so, your verify_login() function should be like this:

```
def verify_login():
    file = open("login.txt","r")
    for row in file.readlines():
        field = row.split(",")
        if username.get().rstrip() == field[0] and password.get().rstrip() == field[1]:
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Fail")
```

Comment: I have just tried this, it works, but it comes up with it failing a few times first in the console

```
Fail
Fail
Fail
Fail
Correct!
Fail
Fail
Fail
Fail
Fail
```

Comment: okay, thats because we're not doing anything if the user is verified. to get rid of this print messages, you can do this:

if username.get().rstrip() == field[0] and password.get().rstrip() == field[1]:
            print("Correct!")
            break

also, totally remove the else block. @Yex

Comment: this works @fayez, but now, if i put the incorrect details in the entry, the console will still print correct, so its not validating the actual entry

Comment: i have edited the code. you should do: `file.readlines()`. I think that will fix the bug. @Yex

Comment: this works for incorrect details, but does not work for correct details now xD

Comment: can you print the username.get() and password.get() and let me know if these are passing the inputs you are providing!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222525/discussion-between-fayez-and-yex).

Answer (score 1):

your text file format

> login,a,yex,joe,morgan,1,sanjay,2

apears to have the type of values stored in the first word *login*

this means when you access item 0 from the list you are getting "login" instead of "a"

you should change the index you try to acces to 1 & 2 instead of 0 & 1

```
def verify_login():
file = open("login.txt","r")
for row in file:
    field = row.split(",")
    if username.get() == field[1] and password.get() == field[2]:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Fail")
```

Comment: I have tried doing this, with all of the username and passwords,and it still dosent work :(

Answer (score 1):

The below should work for you.

`verify_login` is a boolean function now.

```
def verify_login(user_name,password):
    with open("login.txt","r") as f:
      for row in f:
          row = row.strip()
          field = row.split(",")
          if user_name == field[0] and password == field[1]:
              return True
      return False

print(verify_login('Jack','pp'))
print(verify_login('usr1','pwd1'))
```

login.txt

```
usr1,pwd1
usr5,pwd5
```

output

```
False
True
```

Comment: I have tried this but it comes up with this error:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: verify_login() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'user_name' and 'password'

Comment: you need to pass the user_name and the password to the function call. See my example. `verify_login('Jack','pp')`